# PHP ERROR: What is wrong with these php code? It says undefined index error

Tags: php, mysqli

My code:

```
$name=$_POST["name"];
```

This is the error

> Notice: Undefined index: name in /home/u615903880/public_html/reg3.php
>   on line 4

```
code :

<?php
$con          = new mysqli("xxxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");
$name         = $_POST["name"];
$username     = $_POST["username"];
$emailaddress = $_POST["emailaddress"];
$password     = $_POST["password"];
$statement    = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO users (name, username, emailaddress, password)VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssss", $name, $username, $emailaddress, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
$response            = array();
$response["success"] = true;
echo json_encode($response);
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

> Error lines 4,5,6,9,10,14

Comment: Maybe there is no post item like `name` ?

Comment: try to check if the name of your element is : name

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : 'nothing provided';
```

You can put anything instead of `'nothing provided'` like `NULL` or something

Comment: <?php
$con = new mysqli ("mysql.hostinger.ph", "u615903880_user", "matchmixer");    
$name=$_POST["name"];
$username=$_POST["username"];
$emailaddress=$_POST["emailaddress"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
$statement= mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO users (name, username, emailaddress, password)VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssss", $name, $username, $emailaddress, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute ($statement);
$response=array();
$response["success"]= true;
echo json_encode($response);
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);
?>

Comment: error lines 4,5,6,9,10,14

Comment: remove the login details from the code

Answer (score 1):

Its Notice not an error:

you can use

```
error_reporting(1);
```

on top of page this will hide warnings and notices.

or you can use code this way

```
if(isset($_POST["name"])){
 $name=$_POST["name"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't send a `POST` variable called name. If it was from an HTML form, make sure the input is not disabled or it won't post. Also, make sure your form field has a name and not just an id, as it is the name that is used in a post request:

```
<input type="text" id="notused" name="used" />
```

In which case `$_POST['used']` would work upon submission.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the key 'name' is not defined in the $_POST array.
to check for missing key you could use:

```
$name = $_POST["name"]??null; // PHP /7+
```

or

```
$name = isset($_POST["name"])?$_POST["name"]:null; // older
```

Comment: <?php
$con = new mysqli ("mysql.hostinger.ph", "u615903880_user", "matchmixer");    
$name=$_POST["name"];
$username=$_POST["username"];
$emailaddress=$_POST["emailaddress"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
$statement= mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO users (name, username, emailaddress, password)VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssss", $name, $username, $emailaddress, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute ($statement);
$response=array();
$response["success"]= true;
echo json_encode($response);
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);
?>

Comment: errors line 4,5,6,9,10,14

Comment: remove your login details @ArhbencelLopez

Comment: ... and change your mysql credentials asap :) Anyway, are you sure you call this script with a POST request ? Whats your page output if you put die(print_r($_POST,true)); just as a first line in the php block ?